# Correctly format \vdots in small matrix

Tags: math-mode, spacing, matrices

I want to format this matrix in the `\scriptsize` font size:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\scriptsize

$S=\begin{pmatrix}\sigma_1 & 0     & 0\\ 
                0        &\sigma_2 & \vdots\\
                0        &\dots    &
\end{pmatrix}$

\end{document}
```

It does however look unbalanced - there is unwanted whitespace between the first and second row and the `\vdots` are taller than the `$0$` in the second row. What is the best way to correctly typeset this expression?

**Edit 1:**

A workaround would be to simply write

```
$$S=\text{diag}(\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\ldots,0,\ldots),$$
```

where the term `$0,\ldots$` signifies that the matrix has to be filled up with zeros, as `$S\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$`. I would still like to know how to correctly typeset the matrix though.

**Edit 2:**

I want to copy this matrix from a reference source. There it looks like this:

[image]

It appears that the whitespace between the dots has been adjusted, and that they were also shifted manually in the vertical direction. I feel like the ideal option would be to align the top most dot with the top of the `0` and the bottom most dot with the bottom of the `$2$`. Is there a way to format the matrix like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I propose a `\svdots` macro for “scaling” vertical dots. I've never really liked the standard definition, to be honest.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\svdots}{% s for `scaling'
  \vbox{%
    \baselineskip=0.33333\normalbaselineskip
    \lineskiplimit=0pt
    \hbox{.}\hbox{.}\hbox{.}%
    \kern-0.2\baselineskip
  }%
}

\begin{document}

$S=
\begin{pmatrix}
  \sigma_1 & 0        & 0\\ 
  0        & \sigma_2 & \svdots\\
  0        & \dots    &
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
  \sigma_1 & 0        & 0\\ 
  0        & \sigma_2 & 0\\
  0        & \dots    &
\end{pmatrix}$

\scriptsize

$S=\begin{pmatrix}
  \sigma_1 & 0        & 0\\ 
  0        & \sigma_2 & \svdots\\
  0        & \dots    &
\end{pmatrix}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the vertical dots centered with respect to the formula axis, you can do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\svdots}{% s for `scaling'
  \vcenter{%
    \offinterlineskip
    \hbox{.}
    \vskip0.25\normalbaselineskip
    \hbox{.}
    \vskip0.25\normalbaselineskip
    \hbox{.}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

$S=
\begin{pmatrix}
  \sigma_1 & 0        & 0\\ 
  0        & \sigma_2 & \svdots\\
  0        & \dots    &
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
  \sigma_1 & 0        & 0\\ 
  0        & \sigma_2 & 0\\
  0        & \dots    &
\end{pmatrix}$

\scriptsize

$S=\begin{pmatrix}
  \sigma_1 & 0        & 0\\ 
  0        & \sigma_2 & \svdots\\
  0        & \dots    &
\end{pmatrix}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for these suggestions, they already look really good! The formatting is however still slightly off compared to the reference that I am trying to copy this matrix from, do you mind having a look at my second edit?

Comment: @Skydiver Added as requested

Comment: Thank you very much, this works as expected.

Answer (score 3):

I would do that with  `stackengine` , which has a `\Vectorstack` command for math mode:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stackengine}

\begin{document}

\scriptsize

$S=\begin{pmatrix}\sigma_1 & 0 & 0\\
                0 &\sigma_2 & \Vectorstack{\vdots}\\
                0 &\dots &
\end{pmatrix}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

For a \vdots centred w.r.t. the middle of the 0 in the row, you can try this:

```
$S=\begin{pmatrix}\sigma_1 & 0 & 0\\[0.5ex]
                0 &\sigma_2 & \raisebox{-0.12\height}[0pt][0pt]{$\vdots$}\\[0.5ex]
                0 &\dots &
\end{pmatrix}$
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but now the `\vdots` are still not vertically centered in the second row. Is it possible to align them correctly as well?

Comment: The middle dot is aligned on the baseline.  What do you want exactly?

Comment: Fair enough, I was hoping to have the middle dot aligned with the middle of the $0$ however.

Comment: @Skydiver: I've posted another code to satisfy your requirement. I'm not sure it looks beter than the other solution, and the code is more complex, though.

Answer (score 3):

Using the package `nicematrix` adjusting the values of `\NiceMatrixOptions` to `-5pt` (minimum value),

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-top-limit=-5pt,cell-space-bottom-limit=-5pt}
$S=\begin{pNiceMatrix}
\sigma_{1} & 0 & 0\\
0 & \sigma_{2} & \vdots \\
0 & \ldots &
\end{pNiceMatrix}$

\end{document}
```

you can obtain similar output.

[image]